# Connecting lines of same name in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, dissolve, polygon-creation, union

I have street data where roads are segmented for no particular reason. I want to merge/dissolve/union whatever seems fit to make a single flat line.

I have tried above processes in QGIS but every time I start edit in QGIS and start deleting the vertexes of that line the vertex jumps around as if that line is still segmented. I have attached one image where you can see how a dissolved line when edited its vertex are not deleted in straight path rather its jumps around.

So the questions is how can I make a single, straight, flat line out of segmented based on road names.

[image]

Comment: Possibly the combined lines are actually multilinestring objects, where each segment is a separate part of a multipart line. You can find out if that's the case by running `multipart to singlepart`. Once you know that, then we can work on a solution. I think the `merge lines` tool would work for that.

Comment: Yes the merge file tool does the trick but to make it work i have to select the road segments manually. That will be hectic task for 1K+ roads. In my earlier experience with ArcGIS i have seen there is an option while using dissolve that we can tick an option to unsplit the final merged lines to make a single line. But there is no such option or work around in Qgis.

Comment: Also multi part to single part does splits the line again. so that confirms even after dissolve like is still multipart.

Answer (score -1):

Select your road segments (by hand or by query) and try "**merge selected features**" (of the advanced digitizing toolbar) ? But i don't see why you would have to play with individual vertices ...

Comment: Merging 1K+ roads manually is hectic, that's the reason looking for a help. Its rather an itch than a need. I know everything can be done on the dissolved line. But...….

Comment: Hard to diagnose if you don't provide even a subset of your data ...